# Javascript validation for a method calling onLoad()

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I have a form with few text fields and drop downs.

Iam calling a method `onLoad`,validating those text fields and dropdowns in that method.

The user must select one of the options from the dropdown.

The dropdown should not be empty, hence I have a condition like `if(empList==" ")`, if it is empty an alert will popup saying that shouln't be empty.

Now,the actual problem is that the alert is popping-up once I enter into that page, before I select any option as I have given that in `onLoad`.

How should I validate that field?? (I should compulsary call that method onLoad)

Comment: why can't you call it from another event?

Comment: maybe you need just remove from dropdown an empty item so it's no need validation

Comment: In onload add an eventListener for onchange with callback as form validation function.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to instead call your validation method from like the `onchange` event of the `select` tag if you want to validate as soon as changes are made to the selection.

Actually, the best thing would be to put call the your validation function in the `onclick` event of a `button` tag used to submit the form, and in that case, ensure to not set its type to `submit` but instead set it to `button`, so that the form isn't automatically submitted before you make validation.

Then in the validation method, if all is ok, then manually submit the form by doing this:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all the validation on the Submit of the form.

```
<FORM 
     ACTION="../...jsp"
     NAME="testform" 
     onSubmit="return validate()"
     >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using obstrusive popup, you'd better use asynchronous validation that will display alert or info if the form is not filled properly.

Some framework plugins can do it natively : have a look here for instance : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation